# Selenium is throwing selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!doctype html> error on Driver setup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium Version : 4.15.2
Google Chrome : Google Chrome 119.0.6045.159
Chrome Driver: ChromeDriver 119.0.6045.105
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
While driver setup getting exception and not chrome is not getting launched.

```
E           selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!doctype html>
E           <html>
E           <head>
E           <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url="/>
E           </head>
E           <body>
E           </body>
E           </html>
```